# Экспорт объектов из Blender в Unity

Tags: unity3d, 3d, blender

при импорте 3D модели в Unity из Blender столкнулся с проблемой. Модель из себя представляет большое здание и при импорте в Unity стены состоят как будто из одной грани, которая стоит посередине. В Blender показывается все корректно, стена состоит из друг граней и никаких проблем нет. Экспортирую из Blender в формате .fbx при экспорте .obj такая же проблема. Прикрепил скриншоты для лучшего понимания ситуации, так как словами трудно это описать, надеюсь на помощь.

[image: Unity]

[image: Blender]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо развернуть нормали
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html

Ctrl+N  -> Recalculate Normals

Должно все автоматом развернуть, или вручную для каждого полигона разворачивай

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Помогло, только прежде нужно нормали флипнуть Normals -> Flip.
Здесь нашел решение 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXXPnY_2nzg&ab_channel=VincentO%27Reilly
Спасибо за наводку